# Is there a way to test which combinations return a result?

Tags: c#, mysql

OK, to clarify, I have a method that gets a string from the database, depending on the input form a form, from a series of 4 combo boxes.

Thing is, in the Db, some entries are missing fields, meaning that some queries would return nothing.

Is there a way to automatically test which fields won't return a value, or would it be better to alter the query?

Here's my current code:

Form:

```
private void cmbCoreCfg_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbCoreCfg.Text != "" && cmbMetal.Text != "")
    {
            CableID_Controller.GetSupplierId(this);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public static void GetSupplierId(CableID_CreateView CView)
{
    SupplierID_Controller.SModel = new SupplierID_Model();

    SupplierID_Controller.SModel.SupplierID = 3;
    SupplierID_Controller.SModel.CoreConfig = CView.cmbCoreCfg.Text;
    SupplierID_Controller.SModel.Insulation = CView.cmbInsulation.Text;
    SupplierID_Controller.SModel.Xsec = CView.cmbXsec.Text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
    SupplierID_Controller.SModel.CondConfig = condCfg = CView.cmbXsec.Text.Split('-')[1].Trim();
    SupplierID_Controller.SModel.Metal = CView.cmbMetal.Text;

    Database_Facade.Operation_Switch(SupplierID_Controller.OPREAD);

    CView.txtProductCode.Text = SupplierID_Controller.SModel.PrdtCd;
}
```

Database Query:

```
{
    mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT PrdtCd FROM SupplierInfo WHERE Xsec = @Xsec AND CoreConfg = @CoreConfg AND CondConfg = CondConfg "
        + "AND Insul = @Insul AND Metal = @Metal;";

    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Xsec", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CoreConfg", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CondConfg", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Insul", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Metal", MySqlDbType.VarChar);

    mySqlCommand.Parameters["@Xsec"].Value = SModel.Xsec;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters["@CoreConfg"].Value = SModel.CoreConfig;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters["@CondConfg"].Value = SModel.CondConfig;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters["@Insul"].Value = SModel.Insulation;
    mySqlCommand.Parameters["@Metal"].Value = SModel.Metal;

    mySqlReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (mySqlReader.Read())
    {
        SModel.PrdtCd = Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["PrdtCd"]);
    }
    mySqlReader.Close();
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: There's a couple of ways to skin this cat. If your combo box options are only loaded from values in the database, then you know that at least those values are there. Assuming you do this, but then maybe your combination of values isn't there, I would vote to let it hit the database and deal with an empty return with the appropriate message. If you're options are very generic, and most of the time they will return a value, it might be possible to cache combinations that won't return a value. But I think that is overkill, and you should just let it hit the database

Comment: @Prescott Scratch that last comment. The issue is being caused by the fact that the first two combos' data do not always coincide. That's where the issue is. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: An alternative solution is to lazy load the combo boxes based on the selection of the combo box before it. That would require an ajax call to update the next box, and that would have to make sense for your user flow.